# Jenkins agent pod fails to run on kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have installed `jenkins` on a GKE cluster using the stable helm [chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins).

I am able to access and login to the UI.

However, when trying to run a simple job, the agent pod fails to be created.

The logs are not very informative on this

```
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins 2020-01-28 18:30:46.523+0000 [id=184]  WARNING o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Error in provisioning; agent=KubernetesSlave name: default-ld008, template=PodTemplate{inheritFrom='', name='default', slaveConnectTimeout=0, label='jenkins-kos-jenkins-slave ', serviceAccount='default', nodeSelector='', nodeUsageMode=NORMAL, workspaceVolume=EmptyDirWorkspaceVolume [memory=false], containers=[ContainerTemplate{name='jnlp', image='jenkins/jnlp-slave:3.27-1', workingDir='/home/jenkins/agent', command='', args='${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}', resourceRequestCpu='500m', resourceRequestMemory='1Gi', resourceLimitCpu='4000m', resourceLimitMemory='8Gi', envVars=[ContainerEnvVar [getValue()=http://jenkins-kos.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:8080/jenkins, getKey()=JENKINS_URL]]}]}
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pod has terminated containers: jenkins/default-ld008 (jnlp)
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.AllContainersRunningPodWatcher.periodicAwait(AllContainersRunningPodWatcher.java:166)
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.AllContainersRunningPodWatcher.periodicAwait(AllContainersRunningPodWatcher.java:187)
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.AllContainersRunningPodWatcher.await(AllContainersRunningPodWatcher.java:127)
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher.launch(KubernetesLauncher.java:132)
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:290)
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:71)
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins 2020-01-28 18:30:46.524+0000 [id=184]  INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#_terminate: Terminating Kubernetes instance for agent default-ld008
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins Terminated Kubernetes instance for agent jenkins/default-ld008
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins Disconnected computer default-ld008
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins 2020-01-28 18:30:46.559+0000 [id=184]  INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#deleteSlavePod: Terminated Kubernetes instance for agent jenkins/default-ld008
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins 2020-01-28 18:30:46.560+0000 [id=184]  INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#_terminate: Disconnected computer default-ld008
jenkins-kos-58586644f9-vh278 jenkins 2020-01-28 18:30:56.009+0000 [id=53
```

Here are the `kubernetes` events

```
0s          Normal    Scheduled                pod/default-zkwp4                   Successfully assigned jenkins/default-zkwp4 to gke-kos-nodepool1-kq69
0s          Normal    Pulled                   pod/default-zkwp4                   Container image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.4.0" already present on machine
0s          Normal    Created                  pod/default-zkwp4                   Created container
0s          Normal    Started                  pod/default-zkwp4                   Started container
0s          Normal    Pulled                   pod/default-zkwp4                   Container image "jenkins/jnlp-slave:3.27-1" already present on machine
0s          Normal    Created                  pod/default-zkwp4                   Created container
0s          Normal    Started                  pod/default-zkwp4                   Started container
0s          Normal    Pulled                   pod/default-zkwp4                   Container image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.4.0" already present on machine
1s          Normal    Created                  pod/default-zkwp4                   Created container
0s          Normal    Started                  pod/default-zkwp4                   Started container
0s          Warning   Unhealthy                pod/default-zkwp4                   Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.15.2.113:15020/healthz/ready: dial tcp 10.15.2.113:15020: connect: connection refused
0s          Warning   Unhealthy                pod/default-zkwp4                   Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.15.2.113:15020/healthz/ready: dial tcp 10.15.2.113:15020: connect: connection refused
0s          Normal    Killing                  pod/default-zkwp4                   Killing container with id docker://istio-proxy:Need to kill Pod
```

The TCP port for agent communication is fixed to 50000

[image]

Using `jenkins/jnlp-slave:3.27-1` for the agent image.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

**UPDATE 1**: Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/pkaramol/ae51893333f80750891c664088a34cec) with the description of the failed agent.

**UPDATE 2**: Managed to pinpoint the actual error in the `jnlp` logs using stackdriver (although not aware of the root cause yet)

```
"SEVERE: Failed to connect to http://jenkins-kos.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:8080/jenkins/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

**UPDATE 3**: Here comes the weird(est) part: from a pod I spin up within the `jenkins` namespace:

```
/ # dig +short jenkins-kos.jenkins.svc.cluster.local
10.14.203.189
/ # nc -zv -w 3 jenkins-kos.jenkins.svc.cluster.local 8080
jenkins-kos.jenkins.svc.cluster.local (10.14.203.189:8080) open
/ # curl http://jenkins-kos.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:8080/jenkins/tcpSlaveAgentListener/


  Jenkins
```

**UPDATE 4**: I can confirm that this occurs on a GKE cluster using **`istio`** `1.4.0` but **NOT** on another one using `1.1.15`

Comment: The slave connects back to Jenkins via JNLP on JNLP port (TCP port for incoming agents). If you will go to Manage > Configure Global Security; you would be able to see that; select Fixed port and specify a value say 50000.
You can also use tunnel under kubernetes plugin config (Manage> configure system) and specify jenkins.jenkins.svc:50000. (if your namespace is jenkins and serive exposed name is jenkins too)

Comment: I have updated my question; the setting you suggest has already been taken care of. The issue is I am installing the helm chart with most values equal to the default ones; I am pretty sure at some point this worked...

Comment: Yeah I noticed the event logs later

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your scenario, all information you can provide about versions, resources, hosting, services, etc will be of great value!

Comment: The pod you started in jenkins namespace - do it have the sidecar injected? Can you check the envoy logs of the sidecars on both slave and master?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Νο Ι didn't find time to deal with it any further. It just seems `helm` chart of jenkins doesn't work (at least) with `istio` `1.4.0`

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the sidecar proxy for agents.

Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configuration -> Kubernetes Cloud.

Select Annotations options and enter the below annotation value.

```
sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
```